# How to emit from Client Side to a routes file with Socket.io in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, routes

So I'm using a singleton pattern to set up my websocket.

```
var sio = require('socket.io')
var io = null;

exports.io = function () {
  var socket; 
  if(io === null){ // Initialise if not already made 
    io = initialize(server);
  }
  return io;
};

exports.initialize = function(server) {

  io = sio.listen(server);
  var connections = [];

  console.log('IO Initialized!\n')

  io.on('connection', function(socket){
    connections.push(socket);
    console.log('Connected: %s sockets connected', connections.length);

    socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
      connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);
      console.log('Disconnected: %s sockets connected', connections.length);
    });

    // Update function used to send messages to and from backend 
    socket.on('update', function(data){
      io.sockets.emit('new message', {msg: data});
    });


  });

};
```

And then in my public/javascript files I can call these like so

```
$(function(){

    var socket = io.connect();
    socket.emit('update', 'Test Update');
    socket.on('update', function(data){
       console.log('here: ' + data);
    });
});
```

and in my route file I have

```
router.use(function(req, res, next){
    if(socket === undefined){
        socket = io.io();
    }
    next();
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next){


    socket.on('update', function(data){
        console.log('in routes');
    });

    socket.emit('update', 'leaving routes');
});
```

I can emit successfully from the routes file to the public js file (from back end to front end). However, I can't send information from the public js file to the routes file, it only sends to the singleton pattern js file. How can I get it to send to the routes file instead? If I'm going about this the wrong way could somebody please provide an exapmle of how to communicate between a route and a public js file?

Comment: You see to be misunderstanding what `socket` is.  It's a unique object for every incoming client connection.  It's not a singleton.  You can't just refer to it as a global.  In fact, the only place you can really use it is inside the `io.on('connection', ....)` handler because that's where you get offered each new `socket` object that connections.  If what you're trying to do in your routes is to access the socket object that corresponds to a particular user's who is making a request at that moment, then that's a whole different question and there are many other answers here that explore that.

Comment: I'd suggest you search here for "access socket.io connection inside Express route" and see what you find.  The usual way to connect the two is via a session object and you do some initialization in the session when the socket.io connection connects so that later in a route, you can look in the session to get access to the socket.id from which you can get the socket object.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there's nothing wrong with your singleton setup.

*However*, every place where you're going to be listening for events, you have to wrap it in `io.on('connection', ...)`. Making it a singleton doesn't prevent this from being a requirement.

Edit: I *may* be wrong here, I've just noticed that `exports.initialize` isn't actually returning `connections`. Tried that?